# How to create an instance and adding data of base class without object initializer

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a base class and want to create a new instance that inherts from this base class.
So I wrote this Create methode, but how can I get the data of the base class.

I don't want to use an object initializer.

This doen't work (is null):

```
var result = ccuObjectBase as CcuChannelObject;
```

Code

```
internal class CcuChannelObject : CcuObjectBase, ICcuObject
{
    public static CcuChannelObject Create(CcuObjectBase ccuObjectBase)
    {
        var result = new CcuChannelObject();

        result.Datapoints = ccuObjectBase.JsonObject.GetDatapoints();

        return result;
    }

    public List<Datapoint> Datapoints { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but shouldn't it be var result = CcuChannelObject.Create(YourBaseOjbectHere); ?

Comment: Same problem as @ZoharPeled. calling the create class method is an easy answer, but the way you've asked your question, suggests that it's not the right answer. Given your code you've attempted to cast ccuObjectBase to a CcuChannelObject, so to get null, ccObjectBase must be null.

Comment: Why would you even do that conversion? You should be able to access properties of a base class from instance of a derived class if you designed them to be accessible (public, protected).

Comment: Because frist O gather some propeties in the base class, and late know which type of class it should be. So I want create this class but still keep the properties from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the instance of the `CcuObjectBase` then maybe you should use association instead of inheritance.  So your class would look like this:

```
internal class CcuChannelObject : ICcuObject
{
    private CcuObjectBase _ccuObjectBase;

    public CcuChannelObject(CcuObjectBase ccuObjectBase)
    {
        _ccuObjectBase = ccuObjectBase;
        Datapoints = ccuObjectBase.JsonObject.GetDatapoints();
    }

    public List<Datapoint> Datapoints { get; set; }
}
```

The calling code would be something like:

```
var ccuObjectBase = new CcuObjectBase();
/*
...
processing to work out what object you want
...
*/
var ccuChannelObject = new CcuChannelObject(ccuObjectBase);
```

Obviously you will need to change your class names to match the new design.